# Hausdorff measure of Cantor set

Tags: real-analysis, cantor-set, hausdorff-measure, fractal-analysis

I am trying to find a set $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ with Hausdorff dimension $\log2/\log3=:s$ but has $H^s(A)=\infty$.

I suspect this is the Cantor set, but im struggling to show that it has Hausdorff measure (w.r.t $s$) $\infty$.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: The Cantor set does not have infinite $\log_3(2)$-dimensional Hausdorff measure (I would say that the $\log_3(2)$-dimensional Hausdorff measure of the Cantor set is $1$, but this could be off by a constant, depending on the precise definition of the Hausdorff measure used), though some variation of the Cantor set is likely a good place to start looking for examples.

Comment: It might be helpful to think of more elementary examples first.  Can you think of a set of Hausdorff dimension $1$ with infinite $1$-dimensional Hausdorff measure?  What is property or properties might such a set have?  Can you use that example to produce other examples with dimension other than $1$?

Comment: I think this is where my confusion lies. How can a set have Hausdorff dimension 1, but have 1-dimensional Hausdorff measure infinity? Isn't the Hausdorff dimension the infimum of $s>0$ s.t. the s-dimensional Hausdorff measure is 0?

Comment: What is the Hausdorff dimension of the real line?  What is its $1$-dimensional Hausdorff measure?